# Linux CPU consumption

Tags: linux, vmware

We have Linux Vm in our environment (rhel 5.11) . It's showing average CPU consumption +90%(%sys,%usr consumed but not %iowait) checked by sar and top.

Now when I see top or ps outputs , it's showing **no offending processes**.

Checked the machine from esxi as well (using esxtop) , there also it's showing CPU consumption on machine.

Any suggestions what to troubleshoot further ?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly seems the ESXI host is starved for resources.

You should identify which machines are competing for resources (I/O, RAM, CPU), as the starvation of one resource normally affects the others.

Maybe you have misbehaved servers, over-provisioned servers, too much things running on them, or simply maybe is time to redistribute some VMs to other virtualisation hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. Finally got solution for the problem, it was due to a user who was using wrong smtp server for sending his email. Resulting in high message queue. Once,its fixed VM cpu consumption and load, all came down fine.